# C# Dice game, Sum returns only sum of last 2 rolls not whole game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sum, average

I'm creating a dice game with 2 dice, i have got it working but only problem is i cant seam to get the Sum from all the rolls(whole game), i only get the sum of last 2 rolls if i use the Sum method, how do i find the Sum of all the rolls? Here's my code:

```
        Console.BufferHeight = 500;
        Random x = new Random();
        int throw_times = 1;

        int[] dice = new int[2];
        dice[0] = x.Next(1, 7);
        dice[1] = x.Next(1, 7);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            dice[0] = x.Next(1, 7);
            dice[1] = x.Next(1, 7);

            int total_var = dice[0] + dice[1];
            int[] total_array = {dice[0] + dice[1]};//total in array

            Console.Write("Throw " + throw_times + ": " + dice[0] + " and " + dice[1] + " = ");
            Console.WriteLine(total_var);
            throw_times++;

            Array.Sort(dice);

            for (int a = dice.Length - 1; a >= 0; a--)
            {
                int s = dice[a];
                Console.WriteLine("#" + s);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total sum: " + dice.Sum());//only returns sum of last 2 rolls
        Console.WriteLine("Average: " + dice.Average());//only return average of last 2 rolls
```

### If anyone has any idea how i can get the total roll sum please answer, greatly appreciated.

Comment: If p.s.w.g answer is correct and helped you please mark it as the real answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sum` and `Average` extension methods will compute the sum and average of what's currently in the array, and because you're re-setting the array with every trial, it will only ever contain the last two items.

To get the sum or average of all the dice rolls, you'd either have to expand your array so that it records all the dice rolls made throughout your program, or just keep a running total (which seems a lot simpler):

```
int[] dice = new int[2];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    dice[0] = x.Next(1, 7);
    dice[1] = x.Next(1, 7);
    sum += dice[0] + dice[1];

    ...
}

Console.WriteLine("Total sum: " + sum);
```

Now it's not entirely clear from your question if you also want the *average* of all the dice rolls, or just the last two, but since you know the sum and you know the total (because that's hard coded in your app), you can compute the average of all dice rolls pretty easily:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total sum: " + (sum / 200)); // 200 because you roll 2 dice in 100 trials
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i should've seen that tho. Thanks again!